# Make a global JS variable change value inside a Drupal.behaviors and call it in another function

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I've created 2 variables as global and I would like to change their value inside my Drupal.behaviors so I can use it from another function, How can I do that ?

pointLayer is not working in my dragPoint function without puting pointLayer as an argument

```
(function ($) {

    var map;
    var pointLayer;
    Drupal.behaviors.OL_lat_long = {
         attach: function (context, settings) {
                // setTimeout(function(){
             map = $('#openlayers-map').data('openlayers').openlayers;
                    pointLayer= map.layers[1];
```

and call it in this one without any argument:

```
Drupal.OL_lat_long.dragPoint = function(){
        var drag = new OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature(pointLayer);
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the point here?

Comment: how can I change the value of the var pointLayer so I can use it in the function dragPoint ? I don't want to use an argument.

Comment: The way you do it (`pointLayer= map.layers[1];`) is correct. If that does not work for you, there might be a problem somewhere else. But I cannot see it in the code you provided (I don't know Drupal.behaviors though).

Answer (score 0):

If you have global variables in JS, you can change them at any place like this:

```
var var_name;
window.var_name = new_value
```